# Wordpress Un-Explainable Theme Issue

Tags: wordpress, fonts, themes, woothemes

To start with some general info I am using the Flatsome Theme, I have been using it for months now and haven't encountered this issue, normally anything I see in the Theme Editor comes out just as I see on screen. Only today right after I fixed another issue where I had to add a bit off CSS code, my Google Fonts on the site stopped working. Of course I took out the edited bit of code and that didn't solve the problem. -- The weird thing is, everything displays fine in the editor, then when published it looks like this -- [image]

When in the editor, this is what I should be seeing: [image]

I have checked to see why Google Fonts wouldn't be working, but that is hard because I see it working in my Dashboard?? Any help please?

Comment: I accidentally flagged this, and was incorrect in doing so - I apologize in advance for that.  Two Stoned Birds, can you clarify what this "edited" code is please?

Comment: Also please edit to use Markdown so we can see the images without clicking through.

Comment: Please dont downvote, I can't do that as I haven't had my account that long :/

Comment: yes it was .featured-title .page-title-inner {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.page-title-inner {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 0px;
    min-height: 60px;
}

Comment: great, now this will be closed? This is a legitimate question and a real error I'm having, I have provided accurate information, I too the bit of code out and still had the issue so that's why I was unsure of to add it or not.